# Warning during analysing CAKeyframeAnimation

Tags: ios, iphone, animation, cakeyframeanimation

I am getting the warning during the analysing my application i am attaching the screen shot,
i am getting `Dead store` value stored for `animationForButton2` during its initialisation
is never read 
[image]

where the `button_2` is the custom `UIButton` how can shut this warning .. ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace the lines that say:

```
CAKeyframeAnimation *animationForButton2 = [CAKeyframeAnimation animation];
animationForButton2 = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
```

With

```
CAKeyframeAnimation *animationForButton2 = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
```

In the original code sample, there's no point in instantiating `animationForButton2` with a `CAKeyframeAnimation`, only to discard that and replace it with another `CAKeyframeAnimation` on the very next line.